# Put shapes in a grid in WPF

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm trying to dynamicaly add a shape to a grid, I'm creating and setting it this way :

```
Rectangle theRect = new Rectangle();
currentRect = theRect;

theRect.VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Top;
theRect.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Left;

theRect.Margin = new Thickness(oldPos.X,oldPos.Y,0,0);

theRect.StrokeThickness = brushWidht;
theRect.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(brushColor);

theRect.Height = newPoint.Y - oldPos.Y;
theRect.Width = newPoint.X - oldPos.X;

theBoard.Children.Add(theRect);
```

But it sticks to the corner of "theBoard" which is the grid where I put it.
Does anybody can help me with this ?
Thanks.

Comment: `Windows.UI.Xaml` namespace belongs to WinRT, not WPF. wrong tag.

Comment: Consider using a Canvas if you want absolute Positioning. Using the margin for that is bad practice.

Comment: Also, using code to create UI elements in whatever XAML-based technology (WPF, Silverlight or WinRT) is a bad practice.

Comment: @HighCore -- why do you consider creating a UI element in code a bad practice? (I certainly do not consider it a bad practice)

Comment: @WPCoder XAML is intended for that. Anyone that does things that are supposed to be made in XAML in any other way, that wrong. Also the other way around, if you do things that are meant to be made in C# in XAML, thats wrong. Period.

Comment: @WPCoder also, given 2 ways of doing the same thing, choosing the way that requires more code is wrong. Less code for the same results is always better that the same results obtained thru more coding. In this case these 10 lines of C# code can be rewritten in 2 lines of XAML.

Comment: @HighCore - Many people would disagree. Building graphical objects in code can often be much more elegant than XAML, which is sometimes very hard to debug or structure properly. Different contexts might well justify different approaches.

Comment: @HighCore - that's your preference, fine and I'm certain has been debated to death in many forums. That's the great thing about the Xaml based platforms like Wpf and WinRt, that everything may be created in markup and code, and that Microsoft didn't make a decision for us. You can pick the right techniques that work well for your projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've decided to have a `Grid` for the parent, I suppose you're trying to put your shape in different "cells", i.e. in different rows and columns. You can do that with the following code:

```
Grid.SetRow(theRect, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(theRect, 1);
```

If you want to set the absolute position of the shape in the parent then a `Canvas` would be a better choice. In this case you could set the offset of the shape inside the parent using the following code:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(theRect, oldPos.X);
Canvas.SetTop(theRect, oldPos.Y);
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Shapes did it perfectly. Thanks.